# The request body contains invalid JSON

Tags: python-requests, discord

I'm trying  to POST to a discord webhook URL using Python Requests but whenever the `embeds` field is present, it returns `{'code': 50109, 'message': 'The request body contains invalid JSON.'}`. If I remove `embeds` and just leave `content` it will send without any errors.

My code is:

```
url = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/[redacted]/[redacted]"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

data = {
  "username": "Webhook",
  "content": "Hello, World!",
  "embeds": [{
    "title": "Hello, Embed!",
    "description": "This is an embedded message."
  }]
}

res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

I've tried various version of the Discord API but the result is always the same.

Comment: I ran your data element through `/usr/bin/jq` and it parsed correctly. You note that if you don't include the `embeds` element then the request is ok. That implies that the formatting of your `embeds` element is what discord doesn't like. I suggest trying (1) putting the `embeds` element content all on 1 line, and (2) formatting it like `/usr/bin/jq` does and passing that directly - extra spaces+newlines included.

Comment: @James McPherson I tried both of your suggestions but it still returns the same error.

Comment: I suggest re-checking the API docs for the particular webhook you're trying to use, and confirm that your payload data includes the elements which the receiver expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by replacing

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

with

```
requests.post(url, json=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think the requests library may be adding a header called `content-type` which conflicts with your header `Content-Type`, which makes the Discord API return an error:

```
url = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/[redacted]/[redacted]"

headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json"
}

data = {
  "username": "Webhook",
  "content": "Hello, World!",
  "embeds": [{
    "title": "Hello, Embed!",
    "description": "This is an embedded message."
  }]
}

res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```